# Apache2: VirtualHost and Django

Tags: apache-2.2, django

We're hosting two sites and don't have a domain name at the moment so we're using the IP address. I want the two sites to be accessed in the following manner:

```
http://123.123.123.123/Site1
http://123.123.123.123/Site2
```

Site1 is a small *About us* type site. Site2 is a Django-based file upload site.

Here's my httpd.conf file:

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/Site2/src/site
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80

# Site1
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName Site1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/Site1
</VirtualHost>

# Site2
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName Site2

    WSGIScriptAlias /Site2 /var/www/Site2/src/site/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/Site2/src/site>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ /var/www/Site2/src/site/static/

    <Directory /var/www/Site2/src/site/static>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Location /var/www/Site2/src/site/static/>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "site"
        AuthBasicProvider wsgi
        WSGIAuthUserScript /usr/local/wsgi/scripts/auth.wsgi
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

123.123.123.123/Site1 works fine. Visiting 123.123.123.123/Site2 only yields the *Index of /Site2* page.

If I re-order the VirtualHost declarations then Site2 works, but Site1 does not.

Am I missing something incredibly crucial?

I've seen this problem crop up on a number of search results and forums but I haven't yet found a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505689/virtual-hosts-on-apache-with-urls-like-subfolders

Comment: Not sure.. can't flag it since the answer is on Stack Overflow.  I'll post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to use an `Alias` directive instead of a virtual host, since you're dealing with a single domain.

See the accepted answer to this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505689/virtual-hosts-on-apache-with-urls-like-subfolders